# Erro em busca pontos de coleta

Tags: typescript, react, react-native, react-navigation

Na semana passada acompanhei a Next Level Week, que trouxe a ideia de criar um sistema para Mobile e Web, a parte web consegui fazer, tudo conforme o vídeo. mas eu estou com um problema até agora na parte do Mobile exatamente no 4 vídeo que deveria me retorna os pontos de coleta já cadastrados. porém o erro que me retorna é esse `[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...points.map...')]`

de acordo com vídeo, está tudo igual, mas mesmo assim me retorna esse erro.

A baixo vai tá o código com tudo que está relacionado ao ponto de coletas

```
interface Point {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  image: string;
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
}



const [points, setPoints] = useState<Point[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    api.get('points', {
      params: {
        city: 'Mossoró',
        uf: 'RN',
        items: [3, 5, 6]
      }
    }).then(response => {
      setPoints(response.data)
      console.log(response.data)
    })
  }, [])

{points.map((point) => (
                <Marker
                  key={point.id}
                  style={styles.mapMarker}
                  onPress={handleNavigateToDetail}
                  coordinate={{
                    latitude: point.latitude,
                    longitude: point.longitude,
                  }}
                >
                  <View style={styles.mapMarkerContainer}>
                    <Image
                      style={styles.mapMarkerImage}
                      source={{
                        uri: point.image,
                      }}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.mapMarkerTitle}>{point.name}</Text>
                  </View>
                </Marker>
              ))}
```

Comment: quando voce da um `console.log()` no `points`, o que aparece?

Answer (score 0):

Parece que sua variável `points` está recebendo o valor `undefined` e por conta disso não pode executar a função `map`. Você possui um `console.log(response.data)` na função que busca os pontos no mapa, verifique no console o que está sendo apresentado, é provável que o valor recebido não seja válido.

Tente colocar uma barra como prefixo no endereço que está sendo passado a API para que a rota acessada em seu *backend* seja a rota de *points* (estou supondo aqui que arquivo api tenha sido construído do mesmo modo como feito no evento NLW):

```
api.get('/points', {
  // Seu código
});
```

Comment: Tentei também colocar dessa forma com uma barra e também continua dando erro. quando eu dou um console.log em response.data, ele me retorna os pontos de coleta. mas continua dando erro no em points.map()...

Comment: Inclua na sua pergunta todo o código do seu arquivo points.tsx, talvez outra parte do fonte esteja interferindo nessa funcionalidade, ou inclua a url para o projeto no github. Adicione à pergunta também a resposta que seu servidor esta retornando, isso é, o resultado de `response.data`.

Answer (score 0):

Tive um erro semelhante a este, no meu caso era o json que o back-end retornava.
Eu estava esperando um: [ { "id": 12,.....},{},{}]
E o back-end me retornava:  { "points": [ {},{},{} ]}

Minha solução foi substituir isso setPoints(response.data);
por isso setPoints(response.data.points);